# Error with kafka Mirrormaker tool [kafka version 0.10]

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to use the mirrormaker tool to replicate data from one primary cluster to backup one, but I got following error.

```
nykpsr000001726$ bin/kafka-mirror-maker.sh --consumer.config config/mirror-consumer.properties --producer.config config/mirror-
producer.properties --whitelist my-replicated-topic

    [2017-02-03 06:17:00,193] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMaker
    Thread)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid timestamp -1
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init>(ProducerRecord.java:60)
            at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$defaultMirrorMakerMessageHandler$.handle(MirrorMaker.scala:678)
            at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:414)
    [2017-02-03 06:17:00,422] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker.
```

bellow is the detail of configuration for consumer and producers.

mirror-consumer.properties

```
group.id=KafkaMirror-test-1
# consumer timeout should be -1 (default)
zookeeper.connect=ldnpsr000001131:2181
auto.offset.reset=smallest
```

mirror-producer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=nykpsr000001726:9092
```

Really appriciate for a quick prompt.

Comment: Can you specify the Kafka version you are running?

Comment: I am running Kafka 0.10 version, and using the third party test tool to generate testing messages. I believe the incompatibilty of pre 0.10 and 0.10 causing this issue. Again, thanks very much for your support @jose.goncabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are facing a problem with the timestamps, the official documentation says:

> Currently, Kafka Streams does not handle invalid (i.e., negative) timestamps returned from the TimestampExtractor gracefully, but fails with an exception, because negative timestamps cannot get handled in a meaningful way for any time based operators like window aggregates or joins.
>
> Negative timestamp can occur for several reason.
>
> 1. You consume a topic that is written by old Kafka producer clients (i.e., version 0.9 or earlier), which don't use the new message format, and thus meta data timestamp field defaults to -1 if the topic is configured with log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime
> 2. You consume a pre-0.10 topic after upgrading your Kafka cluster from 0.9 to 0.10: here all the data that was generated with 0.9 producers is not compatible with the 0.10 message format (and defaults to timestamp -1)
> 3. You consume a topic that is being written to by a third-party producer client that allows for embedding negative timestamps (KafkaProducer does check for negative timestamp an raises an exception for this case preventing invalid timestamp in the first place)
> 4. The user provides a custom timestamp extractor that extracts a timestamp for the payload data (i.e., key-value pair), and this custom extractor might return negative timestamps.

[Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-93%3A+Improve+invalid+timestamp+handling+in+Kafka+Streams) you can read all the information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jose.goncabel , I will check it again.